# HTMLUnitDriver not working + correct maven dependencies?

Tags: javascript, java, maven, selenium, htmlunit-driver

I'm using [`Selenium`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) for `Java` and I'm having problems with the `HTMLUnitDriver`. No matter which website I try or dependencies, it just crashes on almost any `JavaScript` according to the console output. When I use `PhantomJS` instead, it's all good and stuff works just like it does with e.g. `Chrome` or `Firefox`. Also, I'm not sure which dependencies I'm supposed to use for `HTMLUnitDriver`.

The following is supposed to give me [the latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver) of the `HTMLUnitDriver`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>neko-htmlunit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.52.0</version>
</dependency>
```

However, it doesn't. `HTMLUnitDriver` seems to be bundled with `net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.27`, `net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:2.27` and `net.sourceforge.htmlunit:neko-htmlunit:2.27` despite the exclude.

[This](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/htmlunit-driver) repository however suggests that `2.27` is still the latest but it handles any kind of `JavaScript` on websites very poorly so it's unusable.

This is how I start it:

```
HtmlUnitDriver unitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
unitDriver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function registerElement in object [object HTMLDocument]. (https://www.example.com/some-script.js#31)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:894)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:637)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:518)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:774)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:750)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:102)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:991)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:366)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:247)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:800)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:756)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1236)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1136)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:226)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:345)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3178)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2141)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:945)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:521)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:472)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:999)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:250)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:192)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:272)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:160)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:522)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:396)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:313)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:668)
    ... 3 more
```

Not enabling `JavaScript` works better in terms of avoiding the exception but the site needs `JavaScript` so that's not a solution.

Is there anything wrong with my dependencies or is `HTMLUnitDriver` really just "garbage"? The startup time of `PhantomJS` is about 5 seconds which is pretty slow if you just want to parse something once so a more lightweight driver like `HTMLUnitDriver` would come in handy if it worked...

Answer (score 1):

Please note the change of `artifactId`, the latest version as hinted [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver) is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
```

which is based on Selenium `3.4.0`.

You can use Selenium `3.6.0` with HtmlUnitDriver `2.28-SNAPSHOT`.

I suggest as a starting point, that you reference `HtmlUnitDriver` only, and it will get all depdencies transitively, and then you can all other drivers.

Comment: Well, the readme hasn't been updated in 5 months and I'm already using `Selenium` with other drivers so I can't just remove it. I need `Selenium 3.5.3` due to a bug with `PhantomJSDriver`.

Comment: Selenium `3.5.3` already includes HtmlUnit `2.27`, which is the latest released version. Regarding the JavaScript support, please read [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp) suggests that from **`Selenium`** v2.53.0 onwards you need to **explicitly** include **`HtmlUnitDriver`** as a dependency to include it in your **`Selenium-Maven`** Project. Version number of the driver will now track HtmlUnit itself.

Example :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yeah but version `3.6.0` for instance doesn't exist. `LATEST` turns into `2.27` and that version is still really bad like explained in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Errors like

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function registerElement in object [object HTMLDocument].
```

are usually the result of missing support for a special javascript functionality in HtmlUnit. If you like to see this fixed you have to

- [read this (Submitting Javascript bugs)](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html)
- create the bug report for HtmlUnit

And of course unit tests and/or patches are welcome.

Comment: Not really, if the makers just use their `HTMLUnitDriver` on real life websites they would see plenty of issues on their own. They had years to support `JavaScript` properly. `PhantomJSDriver` and all modern browsers work fine so it can't be this hard to make things work. Still thanks for letting me know what you can do about it.